# Is there a Git GUI client for OS X Lion (10.7.5) in 2017?

Tags: macos, git

I've been looking for a Git Desktop client. I'm a high school student with an old early 2008 white MacBook. Its maximum OS is Lion. My hard disk is too small to effectively use two partitions with bootcamp to run Windows. Does anyone know if a GUI client I could install for Lion? Thanks.

Comment: Try [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) but I don't know what OS it needs. However I would ask what files are you putting under got - if for software development you might find the development tools are not working as your teaching lectures say

Comment: @mark I already tried that one and it requires 10.9 Mavericks or later :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I have an app called Github.app  I did a search and it may be called Github Desktop app now. I haven't used mine nor updated it in months. I know there is an update but I haven't installed it.  A google search on Github app will take you to the appropriate location.